# Помогите определить какой POST запрос отправляется

Tags: post, браузер

Есть сайт https://unicode-table.com/ru/tools/decoder/? . Хотел бы при помощи `libcurl` отправлять POST-запрос со своим Unicode-текстом и получать в виде кириллицы. Там есть кусок

```html
<form method="post" action id="tools-form">
```

И внутри нее есть

```html
<textarea style="width:415px; height:200px;" id="ta-left"></textarea>
```

Если чекнуть через google devtools network , то можно обнаружить такой `Request  Payload`

```css
KþECÞB<
8\u042d\u0442\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0441

'¦ÿ!þB
Ð­ÑÐ¾ Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð¼ÐµÑ

Ô
ê"Çè
Û
ê"Èè
à
ê"Ìè
å
ê"Îè
ë
ê"Ôè
ï
ê"Ùè
ö
ê"Þè
ü
þ"íè

þ"÷è

þ"é

þ"¬é

þ"Äé

þ"âé

þ"é

þ"²ç
 
þ"ßä
¥
þ"ã
©
þ"·à
­
þ"âÞ
´
þ"Þ
 Þ2
 ó­0¼
```

Видно , видимо, отправляется такой POST запрос, так как там мой Unicode-текст , но не могу понять из за символов

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что он на клиенте всё делает, ибо в моём Network запросов нет. Также, он продолжает исправно работать при отключении сети. Вы эту форму вручную отправляли?

Comment: Да, там всё делается на JS, вот как это реализовать на JS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267329/converting-unicode-character-to-string-format

Comment: Да и по CORS вы не отправите POST через JS на другой домен.

Comment: @ДмитрийГорный, есть способ проще: `JSON.parse('"\u042d\u0442\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0440"')`

Comment: @vp_arth, как вариант, способов много :)

Comment: Там давался такой код `\u042d\u0442\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0440`. Вижу он есть в `Request payload`. Поменял последнюю цифру на `1`, то есть `\u042d\u0442\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0441` , смотрю в `Network` и он есть в `Request payload`

Comment: Если это не POST запрос, то и libcurl мне ни к чему? Мне нужно что-то типа WinAPI чтобы сымитировать нажатия на клавиатуру, либо не париться и просто скапипастить откуда нибудь алгоритм и вставить в свой код?